# Join array with a comma every two elements

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array

```
$str = $query->get_title(); //Red blue yellow dog cat fish mountain
$arr = explode(" ",$str);

//output of $arr
Array
(
    [0] => Red 
    [1] => blue 
    [2] => yellow 
    [3] => dog 
    [4] => cat 
    [5] => fish 
    [6] => mountain
)
```

Now I want to join the above array with `,` every two words. The expected result is as below

```
$result = "Red blue, yellow dog, cat fish, mountain";
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what's the problem with that?

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad but i will update my post, i want split `Apple is best company in the world` to `Apple is, best company, in the, world`

Comment: How about just iterating over array with `foreach` and putting either ` ` (a space) or `, `?

Comment: is this viral marketing?

Comment: @vietnguyen09 heheh. i was just kidding, but i do like this new version much better. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this, it uses array_chuck, explode, and implode.

```
<?php

$str = "Red blue yellow dog cat fish mountain";

$result = implode(', ', array_map(function($arr) {
    return implode(' ', $arr);
}, array_chunk(explode(' ', $str), 2)));

echo $result;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/52b06d922e3848): `Red blue, yellow dog, cat fish, mountain`

---

Another method using a forloop if you don't like nested methods.

```
<?php

$str = "Red blue yellow dog cat fish mountain";

$words = explode(' ', $str);

foreach ($words as $index => &$word)
    if ($index % 2)
        $word .= ',';

$result = implode(' ', $words);

echo $result;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/051a34f4ff4dd3): `Red blue, yellow dog, cat fish, mountain`

Answer (score 2):

Do you absolutely need to explode the string into an array? If not, this would be a much simpler solution:

```
$str = $query->get_title(); //Red blue yellow dog cat fish mountain
$result = preg_replace('/(\s.*?)\s/',"$1, ",$str);//Red blue, yellow dog, cat fish, mountain
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output='';
$alternate=false;
foreach($arr as $val) {
   $output.=$val.($alternate==true?', ':' ');
   $alternate=($alternate==false);
}
$output=trim($output);
//$output now is what you want.
```